# Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference (CWE ID 611)(6 flaws)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, veracode

The product processes an XML document that can contain XML entities with URLs that resolve to documents outside
of the intended sphere of control, causing the product to embed incorrect documents into its output.
By default, the XML entity resolver will attempt to resolve and retrieve external references. If attacker-controlled XML can be
submitted to one of these functions, then the attacker could gain access to information about an internal network, local
file system, or other sensitive data. This is known as an XML external Entity (XXE) attack.

nothing

```
package com.integratingstuff.jaxb;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.integratingstuff.pojo.Item;

public class DoUnmarshall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
{
            JAXBContext jaxbContext= JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            String xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><item
 price="" description="Test description" catalog-number="10"/>";

            InputStream inputStream = new 
ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
            Item item = (Item) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good reference for getting a solution: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#java

For example, in your case, you would just add these 2 properties to a `XMLInputFactory` and a stream reader:

```
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        // These 2 properties are the key
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
        xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
        // Your stream reader for the xml string
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory
                .createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(yourXMLStringGoesHere));
        final NsIgnoringXmlReader nsIgnoringXmlReader = new NsIgnoringXmlReader(xmlStreamReader);
        // Done with unmarshalling the XML safely
        final Item item = (Item) unmarshaller.unmarshal(nsIgnoringXmlReader);
```

This should also pass the Veracode scan without any XXE issues.

Hope that helps